# How to find only the unique sentences from a list of sentences

Tags: python, set, unique

Ive got a list like this :

```
           ['University', 'Cambridge', 'Lesley University', 'Lesley', 
'Office of Information Technology', 
    'Office', 'of', 'Information', 'Technology', 'MA', 
        'United States', 'United', 'States', 'Lesley University ', ' University', 
        'Lesley University Cambridge']
```

- University(capitalized) should be treated same as university (lowercase)
- Since 'Leslie University' already contains 'University', hence 'University' should be skipped

Hence Id like to print only the most unique supersets, thus output would look like:-

```
['Office of Information Technology', 'MA', 
            'United States', 
            'Lesley University Cambridge']
```

=====================WHAT I TRIED====================================

```
tok= ['University', 'Cambridge', 'Lesley University', 'Lesley', 
    'Office of Information Technology', 
        'Office', 'of', 'Information', 'Technology', 'MA', 
            'United States', 'United', 'States', 'Lesley University ', ' University', 
            'Lesley University Cambridge']
dic={}
for i in [x.lower() for x in tok]:
    dic[i]=1
dic
```

> {'university': 1,  'cambridge': 1,  'lesley university': 1,  'office
>   of information technology': 1,  'ma': 1,  'united states': 1,  'lesley
>   university ': 1,  ' university': 1,  'lesley university cambridge': 1,
>   'lesley': 1}

```
sup_=sorted(jt.keys(), key=len)
se_={}
for i in sup_:
    ctr=0
    status=True

    for k in sup_:
        if i in k.split():
            ctr+=1
            status=status and (i in k.split())
    if status==True:
        #se[i]=1
        #print (ctr)
        if ctr==0:
            se_[i]=1
se_
```

> {'united states': 1,  'lesley university': 1,  'lesley university
>   cambridge': 1,  'office of information technology': 1}

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what the problem is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Comment: Why should `'MA'` be in the output?  It's a case-insensitive substring of `'Information'`.

Comment: @JohnGordon 'MA' stands for Masachusets

Comment: Question looks Vague, because it has a list construct and when you  looks for a unique words in list it will match word to word, secondly as John said  the way question is Framed `MA` should  not be appeared!

Answer (score 1):

How about this code:

```
import re
test = ['University', 'Cambridge', 'Lesley University', 'Lesley', 'Office of Information Technology', 'Office', 'of', 'Information', 'Technology', 'MA', 'United States', 'United', 'States', 'Lesley University ', ' University', 'Lesley University Cambridge']
result = []
for i in range(len(test)):
    str_init = test[i].strip()
    flag_add = True
    for j in range(len(test)):
        # exclude variable same index
        if(i!=j):
            str_include = " "+test[j]+" "
            pattern = r"\s{0}\s".format(str_init)
            if(re.search(pattern,str_include,re.IGNORECASE)):
                flag_add = False
    if(flag_add):
        result.append(str_init)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['Office of Information Technology', 'MA', 'United States', 'Lesley University Cambridge']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could process your data like so:

```
def is_substr(str,l):
  for s in l:
    if s.lower().strip() != str.lower().strip():
      if str.lower().strip() in s.lower().strip():
        return True
  return False

input = ['University', 'Cambridge', 'Lesley University', 'Lesley', 'Office of Information Technology', 'Office', 'of', 'Information', 'Technology', 'MA', 'United States', 'United', 'States', 'Lesley University', 'University', 'Lesley University Cambridge']

sentences = []
for i in input:
  if not is_substr(i,input):
    sentences.append(i)

print sentences
```

Running this produces the output:

```
['Office of Information Technology', 'MA', 'United States', 'Lesley University Cambridge']
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a little hard to know if this is what you need but this function should give you the unique words of your list

```
def unique_universities(text):
    low = []
    for x in text:
        x.replace(' ', '')
        low.append(x.lower())
    return set(low)
```

Is that what you are looking for?